# Facebook OG debugger fails on place:location. Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ my page (https://demo.inc.construction/referrals/9f6bf828c80134b8d3e07b058045fba6acd4e9ac/fb/review) has an error on place:location tags.

Everything seems to be ok as far as the tags go, but why is the tag debugger complaining on the place:location?

`Object at URL 'https://demo.inc.construction/referrals/e194ee413805ba5a6aabf4d34db2066149dc0369/fb/review' of type 'business.business' is invalid because a required property 'place:location' of type 'geo_point' was not provided.`

Tags are there...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here - your tags match the example they give in the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/business.business/ Therefor I'd say, file a bug report, and ask them what's up. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1168934399812874/

You were doing the correct thing, but it broke on the 30th of March 2016.